# Streched Texture

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm new to this community and in the process of learning Blender.
I have a problem that I hope some of you can solve.
I have tried to apply textures to several of my walls but the texture is good in some parts but other parts are streched. In the examples below you can see the result.
Process I followed:

***1ste Cube Top***
Add Mesh > Cube
Altered dimentions X 0.25m / Y 5m / Z 2.5m
Object > Apply > Scale (to set the scale back to 1)
UV Editing > Unwrap (tried: Smart Unwrap, Manunal marking seams and unwraping, and cube projection)
Shading > new material > Add > Texture > Image Texture (tried with both a jpg and a png)

***2nd Cube Bottom***
Add Mesh > Cube
Altered dimentions X 0.25m / Y 5m / Z 2.5m
Object > Apply > Scale (to set the scale back to 1)
UV Editing > Unwrap (tried: Smart Unwrap, Manunal marking seams and unwraping, and cube projection)
Shading > new material

As you can see the texture of the bottom wall is stretched if you compare it to that of the top wall.
I added a Texture coordinates and mapping nodes but that din't help.
The only solution I found is to play with the scale on the mapping node (see pict 5 and 6). I extrapoleted that the Y axis of the bottom wall is 2x larger than that of my top. So I changed the Y scale of the mapping note to 2 (2x larger that the Y scale of the top wall).
If you got only 2 wall that easy, but if you want to create a maze or a building interior it becomes to much work.

***Is there another way to use the texture as a pattern, or did I do something wrong?***

[image: Top Wall]

[image: Bottom Wall]

[image: JPG]

[image: PNG]

[image: Bottom Wall Mapping node scale Y 2]

Comment: you can go into your UV editor, and scale down the part that you don't want to be stretched on the x axis.   If you're not sure how to do this, I would recommend watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM

Comment: You messed up the scale on the mapping node. Why isn't it 1:1:1?

Answer (score 0):

The UV unwrapping is maybe messed up. Try unwrapping that very wall only in the uv editor. If that doesn't help then use the mapping node's scale bar to adjust it. Hope it helps

Comment: we already figured it out, they had their mapping wrong